# die vor einem liegende Aufgabe nicht in hinreichender Qualität erledigen zu können - How does the structure work?

Tags: dative, modal-verb

How does the structure in this sentence work?

> Die Schreibblockade ist sicherlich eine Reaktion des Kopfes auf die Befürchtung, die vor einem liegende Aufgabe nicht in hinreichender Qualität erledigen zu können.

My guess is that `liegende Aufgabe nicht in hinreichender Qualität erledigen zu können` would be a phrase that functions like a noun (i.e `to always learn is good` versus `tomatoes are good`). I don't know how to elaborate on this but hope you can understand), but if that is the case, then what would `einem` do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of the phrase after the comma is called "erweiterter Infinitiv" (extended infinitive). You're right, such a phrase can stand instead of a noun, like in your examples. In this case, it's an apposition to the noun "Befürchtung" that explains this noun nearer (which *Befürchtung*?), like in these examples:

> the excitement to go on a tour
> the fear to not be able to do it

And boy is this infinitive extended.

The shortened and probably more understandable core version is:

> die Befürchtung, die Aufgabe nicht erledigen zu können.
> *(the apprehension of not being able to finish the task)*

The missing rest are just attributive and adverbial phrases fleshing this out:

Which *Aufgabe*?
They're using a participle construction here:

> die vor einem liegende Aufgabe
> *as an equivalent Relativsatz this would be:*
> die Aufgabe, die vor einem liegt,
> *(the task laying before the person)*

The pronoun *einem* refers back to the person that has the *Befürchtung*. If you have doubts about this, that would make a good separate question.

*Erledigen* how?

> in hinreichender Qualität erledigen
> *(to finish in adequate quality)*

Comment: Es liegt vor mir. Es liegt vor dir. Es liegt vor Peter. Es liegt vor jemandem. Es liegt vor einem.